# Jmeter 3.2 unable to Record in https mode

Tags: http, https, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm using Jmeter 3.2,

I'm trying to record a secure https URL but I am not able to record anything.

I have imported the SSL certificate in the browser but still unable to record.

Answer (score 0):

Use firefox

In JMeter use **Recording** template

Start recorder, JMeter generates a CA certificate

Add this (located in jmeter/bin folder) to your browser:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder (Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording)

Start using your application